# Glue Classifier Fails to classify s3 logs using Gork pattern

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

**Problem** : Running the Crawler with a classifier with right gork pattern doesn't create the table with columns instead table with 0 columns and recordCount 0 is created(but objectCount is 5)

**Details** : I set up a Glue Crawler to look at a s3 bucket which has s3-access-logs. This Glue Crawler uses a Classifier to classify columns for each entry in the log file.

The Classifier is setup with a Gork Pattern below

```
%{NOTSPACE:session_uuid} %{NOTSPACE:bucket_name} \[%{DATA:timestamp}\] %{IP:ip_address} %{NOTSPACE:principle} %{NOTSPACE:request_uuid} %{NOTSPACE:bucket_action} %{NOTSPACE:resource} \"%{DATA:resource_action}\" %{NOTSPACE:http_status} %{NOTSPACE:http_error_msg} %{NOTSPACE:unknown1} %{NOTSPACE:unknown2} %{NOTSPACE:unknown3} %{NOTSPACE:unknown4} %{NOTSPACE:url} %{NOTSPACE:client_info} %{GREEDYDATA:rest}
```

And above Gork pattern successfully matches S3 access logs like below when I tested it using [online gork tester](http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match#result)

```
efaeda52d1d3e3aaa719b9cddf4a4dd161157e2f9343635589d5b625ebcba84b my-s3bucket-12345 [12/Dec/2017:13:55:33 +0000] 123.123.123.123 - 2F834DCEE973FF7B REST.HEAD.BUCKET - "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 400 AuthorizationHeaderMalformed 365 - 6 - "-" "AWSConfig" -
efaeda52d1d3e3aaa719b9cddf4a4dd161157e2f9343635589d5b625ebcba84b my-s3bucket-12345 [12/Dec/2017:14:32:29 +0000] 123.123.123.123 arn:aws:sts::1234567890:assumed-role/DataAccessRole 2F834DCEE973FF7B REST.GET.ACL - "GET /information-prefix/?acl HTTP/1.1" 200 - 622 - 237 - "-" "S3Console/0.4" -
```

Answer (score 1):

The GROK pattern in this original question was helpful enough for me to get started with setting up my own crawler.  However, it is definitely incomplete.

Using the documented [Amazon S3 server access log format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/LogFormat.html), I created this pattern which I believe is complete.  Enjoy!

```
%{NOTSPACE:bucket_owner} %{NOTSPACE:bucket} \[%{DATA:time}\] %{NOTSPACE:remote_ip} %{NOTSPACE:requester} %{NOTSPACE:request_id} %{NOTSPACE:operation} %{NOTSPACE:key} \"%{DATA:resource_uri}\" %{NOTSPACE:http_status} %{NOTSPACE:error_code} %{NOTSPACE:bytes_sent} %{NOTSPACE:object_size} %{NOTSPACE:total_time} %{NOTSPACE:turn_around_time} \"%{NOTSPACE:referer}\" \"%{DATA:user_agent}\" %{NOTSPACE:version_id} %{NOTSPACE:host_id} %{NOTSPACE:signature_version} %{NOTSPACE:cipher_suite} %{NOTSPACE:authentication_type} %{NOTSPACE:host_header} %{NOTSPACE:tls_version} %{NOTSPACE:access_point_arn}
```

Note that many of these fields can be **null** and that Amazon puts **-** to represent those values.  Also, note that some of the values are quoted.

Answer (score 0):

Hope its not too late. I think the "IP" is causing problem for you, since it also create UNWANTED portion as well. Just use IPV4 instead of IP. Or you can use NOTSPACE as well.